roundcube 1.6.5 smtp configuration
I have a fresh install of debian 12.5 bookworm with postfix and dovecot installaion.
I have installed roundcube and let it's default configuration.
Not working! It's frustrating! I configured outlook, thundebird, aquamail as email clients.
Everything went ok. With roundcube I cannot send a single email!
My configuration is as follows: Dovecot as IMAP server, Postfix as SMTP server.
The error message is "smtp server connection to server failed" (when I enter config['smtp_server']='ssl://localhost:465" as seen on google.
Whether i put "localhost:587" (the default) or "localhost:465" the error message is "SMTP Authentication failed".
My guess is that there might be an issue with the security certificate for SSL TLS or there might be a problem with debianized roundcube. I mentioned that I used a fresh install of bookworm (debian 12.5) and (almost) standard configuration of postfix. I use MySQL as a backend for IMAP and berkeley db as a backend for smtp.
Thanks for replying. I would like to hear from a somebody who installed the same as me debian 12.5 and roundcube 1.6.5. all fresh install.

Try port 25, check where postfix listen.
